# Cannot bind to TabItem DataContext from the TabItem Content in Silverlight

Tags: c#, silverlight, xaml, tabcontrol, tabitem

I have a TabItem that has it's DataContext set to a ViewModel.
The header is set to a header View and the Content is set to an item view

However this Binding from the item view just doesn't work

```
<TextBox Margin="0" Grid.Column="0" Grid.Row="0" Text="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource FindAncestor, AncestorType=sdk:TabItem, AncestorLevel=1}, Path=DataContext.Job.SourceCode, Mode=TwoWay}"/>
```

yet this binding

```
<TextBlock Text="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource FindAncestor, AncestorType=sdk:TabItem, AncestorLevel=1}, Path=DataContext.Job.Name}"/>
```

which is in the header view works fine.

I've even tried putting the TextBlock from the Header into the Item and setting the Content to a new HeaderView.  No matter what I try I can't get the bindings from the Content to work even though the header binding works fine

Can anyone explain?

Adding the full Views as requested first the Item

```
<UserControl x:Class="IE.Intergration.JobBuilder.Views.TabbedJobs.TabbedJobItem"
xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
    xmlns:sdk="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation/sdk"
mc:Ignorable="d"
d:DesignHeight="300" d:DesignWidth="400" 
    DataContext="{Binding Source={StaticResource ViewModelLocator}, Path=New.TabbedJobs.TabbedJobItem}"
    >
<UserControl.Resources>
</UserControl.Resources>
<Grid x:Name="LayoutRoot" >
    <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
    </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
    <Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <RowDefinition Height="*"  />
        <RowDefinition Height="40"/>
    </Grid.RowDefinitions> 
    <TextBox Margin="0" Grid.Column="0" Grid.Row="0" Text="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource FindAncestor, AncestorType=sdk:TabItem, AncestorLevel=1}, Path=DataContext.Job.SourceCode, Mode=TwoWay}"/>
    <StackPanel Grid.Column="0" Grid.Row="1" FlowDirection="LeftToRight" Orientation="Horizontal">
        <Button Content="Save" Command="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource FindAncestor, AncestorType=sdk:TabItem, AncestorLevel=1}, Path=DataContext.Save}" /> 
    </StackPanel>
</Grid>
```

and the Header

```
<UserControl x:Class="IE.Intergration.JobBuilder.Views.TabbedJobs.TabbedJobItemHeader"
xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
    xmlns:sdk="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation/sdk"
mc:Ignorable="d"
d:DesignHeight="300" d:DesignWidth="400"
    DataContext="{Binding Source={StaticResource ViewModelLocator}, Path=New.TabbedJobs.TabJobHeader}" 
    >

<Grid x:Name="LayoutRoot">
    <TextBlock Text="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource FindAncestor, AncestorType=sdk:TabItem, AncestorLevel=1}, Path=DataContext.Job.Name}"/>
</Grid>
```

Comment: Any binding errors in the VS's Output window?

Comment: In local it gives me {Error: System.Exception:BindingExpression_CannotFindAncestor}
Which I hadn't noticed before. No such error in the HeaderView though. It's like TabItem isn't a parent for the Content.

Comment: The TabItem isn't a parent of the content. You can look at the [TabControl template](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc645035(v=vs.95).aspx) and see that the TabItems go in a `TabPanel` e.g. TabPanelTop and the content goes in a `ContentPresenter` which is a child of a `Border` not the `TabPanel`.

Comment: @bstoney - Yup, that's it. The TabItem is "responsible" for rendering the tab (i.e. header), but not the content.

Comment: Please add the TabControl declaration.  Thanks